# Autenticação sites externos

Tags: react, slim, jwt

Estou utilizando JWT para fazer a autenticação de acesso. Quando tento uma requisição GET de fora do meu sistema, ele exibe essa mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

trecho do código onde faço a requisição (js):

```
[...]
var cep = this.soNumero(this.state.cep);
var cepUrl = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/' + cep + '/json/';
axios.get(cepUrl).then(res => { 
[...]
```

Utilizo React e PHP com o Slim Framework

OBS: Se quiserem testar o link, é só colocar qualquer CEP no lugar da variável no código (Ex.:https://viacep.com.br/ws/37701140/json/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está passando por default um header que o server-side (ViaCEP) não aceita, que é o X-Access. Limpe o seu header default antes da requisição:

```js
axios.defaults.headers.common = {}
axios.get('https://viacep.com.br/ws/01311200/json/')
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```